# code "from simple_cdd.env import environment" where are these packages?

Tags: python-3.x

I can not find import packages localtion.

```
from simple_cdd.env import Environment
from simple_cdd.variables import VARIABLES
from simple_cdd.exceptions import Fail
from simple_cdd.tools import FancyTerminalHandler
from simple_cdd.utils import run_command,verify_preseed_file,shell_quote,shell_which
```

Answer (score 0):

It's in the python3-simple-cdd package, which is under:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simple_cdd
```